# ASP.NET Core: How to localize Html.ValidationMessage?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, localization

I use the following snippet in my `.cshtml` file:

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("loginError")
```

And this in my `Controller`:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("loginError", message);
```

Now I want to localize the message inside my View (not in the controller).

For standard text I use this:

```
@Localizer["Login"]
```

How do I localize the `ValidationMessage`? Can I get the raw message from it and just give it to my `Localizer` or is there a better way?

Comment: You want to localize this message by yourself? `message` is just a string so you ought to put there localized string

Comment: @teovankot Thanks for your answer! I know that `message` is just a string, but that string is inside my `Controller` I could, but I don't want to do the Localization there, because I've already added all my translations in the `.resx` files for the `.cshtml` View

Comment: Don't you want to do it in controller like this:

`ModelState.AddModelError("loginError", Localizer.LoginError);`?

Comment: @teovankot No, because I don't want to DI the Localizer object into my `Controller` only for this. I'd also have to add a new `.resx` file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's my suggestion but it's quite a hack:

```
@Localizer[@ViewData.ModelState["loginError"]?.Errors[0].ErrorMessage ?? ""]
```

Using this inside my View works. But I'm open to better solutions...

Answer (score 0):

I think i have found a better solution:

1. Inject IStringLocalizerFactory factory
2. Create localizer: _localizer = factory.Create(typeof(LoginModel));
3. ModelState.AddModelError("loginError", message);

Store the message in resource file that contains model type specific validation messages.